# Why php generator is slower than an array?

Tags: php, performance, foreach, generator

According to comments from documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php
We can see that thanks to generators there is huge memory usage improvement (which is obvious), but there is also 2-3 times slower execution - and that is not so obvious to me.

We gain memory usage improvement at the expense of time - which is not fine.
So, why is php generator slower than an array?

Thanks for tips.

Comment: Because it has to run code to fetch the stuff that we didn't fetch to save memory?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah, but in documentation it is provided as solution for problem with time: "A generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over a set of data without needing to build an array in memory, which may cause you to exceed a memory limit, **or require a considerable amount of processing time to generate**"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When doing optimizations a lot of times you have to choose between speed of execution and memory usage i.e precalculating something and storing it or just doing calculations when you need them.

> A generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over
> a set of data without needing to build an array in memory, which may
> cause you to exceed a memory limit, or require a considerable amount
> of processing time to generate

The manual is referring to a situation when you will not iterate through all results that you generate with your generator. The speed benefit will come from the fact that you don't need to waste processing time and memory by generating items that you don't need.

Generators weren't designed to replace arrays. They were intended as a way to reduce boilerplate code when implementing `Iterator` objects. Generators will always be slower than arrays, because generator has to generate values each time you call `next()`.

With generators you can do interesting things that you can't do with arrays - for example you can represent infinite sequences (e.g. you could create a `range` function that only accepts start and step arguments).

I was a little curious so I did a quick comparison between `xrange` (implemented with generators, as on the [PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php)) and the built in `range` function.

Results on my machine (tested with PHP 5.6) were:

range(1, 10000000, 1):

```
time: 5.2702
memory (byte): 1495269376
```

xrange(1, 10000000, 1):

```
time: 1.9010
memory (byte): 262144
```

Note that the "benchmark" code I was using *was* iterating through all results and doing simple math operations. The function calls, as displayed above, serve only as a reference for values I was testing with. As always, with very simple benchmarks like this, YMMV.

Comment: For reference: https://3v4l.org/gXnic/perf#output, https://3v4l.org/kbnNo/perf#output 3v4l does not provide a lot of memory, so I just used 1.0e+5.

Comment: @SOFe nice. With bigger N (i.e. 100k) you see even a bigger difference (PHP 5.6 is bad in both versions). [Range](https://3v4l.org/INjT0/perf#output) vs [Generator](https://3v4l.org/8I9r0/perf#output)

Comment: Now my concern is instead about small amounts. I only have a few items (usually around the magnitude of 10¹-10²) to generate, but I need to generate very frequently. This makes a big N not very meaningful for my use case.

Comment: @SOFe As they say, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Like with all optimiziations, test and measure the optimization for your use case before making the changes :)

Comment: https://3v4l.org/J2Gpj/perf#output https://3v4l.org/mUT3l/perf#output These two tests go with 100000 calls to g(), which either creates an array of 0-9 integers or generates 0-9 integers. As of PHP 7.2.4, arrays seem to be about 60% faster than generators by User Time. This conforms with the OP's description.

Comment: @SOFe Like my answer says - `the generators weren't designed to replace  arrays.They were intended as a way to reduce boilerplate code when implementing Iterator objects.` and `The generators will always be slower when comparing them to arrays, because generator has to generate the values each time you call next() to save memory.` So no surprise here... You're probably just misunderstanding the intended use for generators.

Comment: Generators allow for more elegant code in some cases too (instead of making a class with confusing class properties), when it comes to more complicated logic. It's probably the code elegance vs optimization. Just like you don't want to turn all your `count()` into `\count()` because it doesn't look nice -- but it really works slower.