# PHP OpenDir vs array_rand

Tags: php, time-complexity

I have a directory of images, this could contain anywhere from 100 to many thousands of images. I need to take a sample of 81 random images out of this directory to be used (in an array).

I am currently using the following to grab an image

```
$locations = 'compressed/';
$images = glob($locations . '*', GLOB_BRACE);
$selected = $images[array_rand($images)];
```

The issue with this method is that it is possible to get the same image twice (albeit rarely in large samples)

I have also seen that opendir could be used then shuffling the array. Can someone please tell me which is more efficient to use? I would assume using shuffle then grabbing the first 81 elements would be better but slower for larger counts (as shuffling large arrays would take longer).

Any suggestions on the time complexity of my current setup as opposed to using opendir (or other methods I may not know of)?

Thanks

Comment: Why not test and time them?

Comment: @AbraCadaver because I did not want to have to upload thousands of images to my server to test this if I did not have to

Comment: Testing it locally can give you a good hint as well. Well, at least, if you use the OS and the same filesystem. Good question by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really good question, I wish more of these would come up.

---

```
$start = microtime(true);

function recursiveDirectoryIterator($path) {
  foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $file) {
    if(!$file->isDir()) {
      yield $file->getFilename() . $file->getExtension();
    }
  }
}

$instance = recursiveDirectoryIterator('../vendor');
$files = [];
foreach($instance as $value) {
  $files[] = $value;
}

$total_files = count($files);
$random_array = [];
$total_randoms = 81;
for(;;){
  $rand = random_int(0, $total_files);
  if(count($random_array) == $total_randoms) {
    break;
  }
  if(!isset($random_array[$rand])) {
    $random_array[$rand] = $files[$rand];
  }
}

echo "Mem peak usage: " . (memory_get_peak_usage(true)/1024/1024)." MiB" . '<br>';
echo "Total number of files: " . $total_files . '<br>';
echo "Completed in: ", microtime(true) - $start, " seconds" . '<br>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
die;
```

---

Output

```
Mem peak usage: 2 MiB
Total number of files: 12972
Completed in: 0.74663186073303 seconds
Array
(
    [6118] => PreDec.phpphp
    [4560] => LabelMaker.phpphp
    [10360] => RecursiveDirectoryIterator.phpphp
    [4124] => Enum.phpphp
    [2671] => ImportCommand.phpphp
    [1250] => WebDriverTest.phpphp
    [10518] => AutoExpireFlashBagTest.phpphp
    [6805] => zsdtPackTask.phpphp
    [4288] => HTML.Trusted.txttxt
    [6462] => border-disable.phptphpt
    [4980] => main.ymlyml
    [505] => StepTested.phpphp
    [5219] => xhprof.ini.j2j2
    [12959] => RequestInterface.phpphp
    [1423] => xd5.phpphp
    [4285] => HTML.TidyAdd.txttxt
    [4930] => .travis.ymlyml
    [12013] => Defined.phpphp
    [8779] => Markdown.phpphp
    [5979] => pt.phpphp
    [278] => AbstractAdapter.phpphp
    [2155] => SemVerTest.phpphp
    [523] => ServicesResolverFactory.phpphp
    [11686] => AbstractDumper.phpphp
    [7320] => Functions.phpphp
    [7763] => mocked_clone.tpl.distdist
    [11541] => test_landscape.gifgif
    [3557] => RegionSelectorSpec.phpphp
    [2600] => RoutingAccessSniff.phpphp
    [9496] => LoaderTest.phpphp
    [4958] => setup-RedHat.ymlyml
    [3477] => api.featurefeature
    [7975] => WtfCommand.phpphp
    [9001] => ElseIfDeclarationSniff.phpphp
    [11696] => VarDumperTestTrait.phpphp
    [11211] => empty.ymlyml
    [10925] => ObjectRouteLoader.phpphp
    [10936] => MatcherDumperInterface.phpphp
    [2685] => ConnectCommand.phpphp
    [9066] => EmptyStyleDefinitionSniff.phpphp
    [3536] => BehatTestExtensionInstallStorage.phpphp
    [4720] => ansible-args.mdmd
    [326] => ZipOutputParser.phpphp
    [9565] => BufferedOutput.phpphp
    [712] => CliExtension.phpphp
    [3436] => .travis.ymlyml
    [4471] => HTMLPurifier.kses.phpphp
    [2764] => RouteSubscriberCommand.phpphp
    [10633] => RoutableFragmentRenderer.phpphp
    [6906] => Reference.phpphp
    [11663] => DoctrineCaster.phpphp
    [8042] => GitHubChecker.phpphp
    [1466] => ImageDriverInterface.phpphp
    [2652] => DrupalCommand.phpphp
    [7265] => classUsesNamespacedFunction.phpphp
    [12129] => ExtensionInterface.phpphp
    [12184] => ConditionalExpression.phpphp
    [12128] => EscaperExtension.phpphp
    [6678] => JsHintTask.phpphp
    [5351] => main.ymlyml
    [2104] => _bootstrap.phpphp
    [143] => deploy_branch
    [1360] => x8f.phpphp
    [4713] => composer-dependency.mdmd
    [7495] => ExceptionInAssertPostConditionsTest.phpphp
    [4508] => info.txttxt
    [8369] => 6.1.3-curl-adapter.phpphp
    [3093] => create-data.ymlyml
    [1882] => .gitkeepgitkeep
    [3747] => example.makemake
    [507] => EventDispatchingBackgroundTester.phpphp
    [3336] => shell.ymlyml
    [397] => AnnotationReader.phpphp
    [4005] => xhUnitTest.phpphp
    [5168] => test.ymlyml
    [10909] => MissingMandatoryParametersException.phpphp
    [8686] => FacetSetTest.phpphp
    [2321] => FileCache.phpphp
    [10538] => StreamedResponseTest.phpphp
    [12572] => in.testtest
    [7031] => StringContainsToken.phpphp
)
```

---

Code break down.

I used [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) with a [Generator](http://php.net/manual/ro/language.generators.overview.php) to save up on memory usage.

Next, instead of shuffling a huge array, I chose another approach: generate 81 random, non repeating numbers in the range of max count of the files array and 0. Once you have the random numbers simply use [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-intersect-key.php) which is fairly fast.

Do note a logical pitfall which I didn't take into account:

- If the total number of files is less than 81, the `for` loop will run forever.

---

- [generators performance - speed vs mem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465369/why-php-generator-is-slower-than-foreach)

---

Final note: I'm absolutely sure somebody smarter than me can think of something better, but for now this will work.

Also, since I'm using PHP 7.x I have the advantage of [opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) and performance will be a better on my part, your results may vary.

Please note that if the number of files is very small the `for` loop will run for longer since the change of collision is higher on smaller samples.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for that, I think the number generator is definitely a better way of doing it and glad you had the file system to test it. Fortunately for the purposes of my application, there will never be less than the 81 files in the directory so that caveat (inf. for loop) does not matter :)

Comment: @Andrew does array_intersect_key work differently in PHP 5.3? I switched random_int to rand but $final is always the exact same files (random_array is different so it must not be grabbing the hash or something like that)

Comment: Ooops, you're absolutely correct. My bad, was in a hurry didn't really think that one thru. I've edited the question. Instead of combining the array, you can add the files in the for loop. Check if the array key exists, if it doesn't add it, and that's that. If you need the keys to be in order, do `array_values` on the `$random_array` and ti will reorder it. Since it only has 81 elements, performance will not be a problem.